# Extract specific words from a line

Tags: sed, awk

I hope someone here can help me. I have a line in a text file looking like this:

```
Jan  8 14:12:56 kernel: SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=104 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44224 DPT=14000 LEN=84
```

I want to extract the words starting with SRC=, PROTO= and DPT=. My goal is to end up with a line looking something like this:

```
1.2.3.4 UDP 14000
```

I would prefer the solution being bash using sed, awk or similar if possible.

Comment: What language are you programming in? Some languages will break up the string in one command, while others could take an entire loop. Plus the method is different in each language. P.s. perl is very good at this sort of thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Sed with groups:

```
sed -r 's/.*SRC=(\S+).*PROTO=(\S+).*DPT=(\S+).*/\1 \2 \3/'
```

Comment: You might replace `[^ ]*` by `\S*`

Answer (score 2):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[ =]" } { print $7, $22, $26 }' infile
```

Output:

```
1.2.3.4 UDP 14000
```

Answer (score 1):

If the output is generated in a fixed order, then you could simply use shell builtins.

```
grep SRC= /var/log/messages |
while read mon day time kernel src dst len tos prec ttl id if proto spt dpt etc; do
    echo ${src#*=} ${proto#*=} ${dpt#*=}
done
```

If you have the data in $string and the desired parameters are at fixed positions, you could also

```
set -- $string
echo ${5#SRC=} ${13#PROTO=} ${15#DPT=}
```

If your shell can't handle positional parameters beyond $9 you will need a few `shift`s.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `Grep`:

You can use `grep's` `perl` regular expression to find the text. Here we use a positive look behind. Since the output is displayed on separate line, you can use the `tr` function to replace the `new line` with `space`.

```
grep -Po "(?<=SRC=)[0-9.]+|(?<=PROTO=)([A-Z]+)|(?<=DPT=)([0-9]+)" INPUT_FILE | 
tr "\n" " "
```

#### Test:

#### Step:1: Using grep

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] grep -Po "(?<=SRC=)[0-9.]+|(?<=PROTO=)([A-Z]+)|(?<=DPT=)([0-9]+)" file
1.2.3.4
UDP
14000
```

#### Step:2: Piping the output to `tr`

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] grep -Po "(?<=SRC=)[0-9.]+|(?<=PROTO=)([A-Z]+)|(?<=DPT=)([0-9]+)" file | 
tr "\n" " "
1.2.3.4 UDP 14000
```